# How to using If else for conditional <select> option in PHP?

Tags: php, html, select

The scenario is, I have 3 level user (Employer,Manager,Cashier), if the employer login the page, the employer just can see Manager and Cashier option in the select box;if the manager login the page, the manager just can see Cashier option in the select box

User level number I have stored in this variable $user_level, when the user login the id of the user will record in this variable $user_level. In the user value I have set the user level Employer id is 1, Manager id is 2, Cashier id is 3. For example, when the user level 1 (Employer) login the page, the  option just can show Manager and Cashier option.When the user level 2 (Manager) login the page, the  option just can Cashier option. My problem is how to change below the coding to if/else for conditional  option ?

I have declared `$user_level = $row['user_level'];`

Below is my code:

```
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Position<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <select class="form-control required" id="position" name="position">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="2">Manager</option>
                        <option value="3">Cashier</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Below the coding is check the user login current position(user level number),this part in the future will hidden:

```
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Current Login User Level<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <input disabled type="text" class="form-control required" id="user_level" name="user_level" value="<?php echo $user_level; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Below is my output example:

[image]

Hope someone can guide me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `if-else` logic inline with the options:

```
<?php if($user_level != 3) { ?>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Position<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <select class="form-control required" id="position" name="position">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <?php if($user_level == 1) { ?>
               <option value="2">Manager</option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($user_level == 1 || $user_level == 2) { ?>
                <option value="3">Cashier</option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Updated for revised requirements.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is absolutely right. Cashier user level can't see anything.

Comment: Is possible if cashier login then can't see the "Position" <div>?